# Package documentation in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, documentation

Does exist a way to open/read the documentation of packages directly from TeXworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built-in, but TeXworks does allow for extensions via scripts. If you look in the [TeXworks repository at Github](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/) there is one script for doing what you ask:

- https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/261#issuecomment-80296662

I tried this on my system (Kubuntu with TeX Live), and it seemed to work fine. The steps to use it is as follows:

1. Download the ZIP archive from the link above.
2. Open TeXworks, choose Scripts --> Scripting TeXworks --> Show scripts folder:

   [image: scripts menu in TeXworks]
3. Unzip the archive in this folder, it should give you a subfolder called `packageHelp` containing a `.txt` file and a `.js` file.
4. In TeXworks, choose Scripts --> Scripting TeXworks --> Reload scripts folder. If you now look in the Scripts-menu again, there should be an entry `packageHelp` (as in the image above).
5. You need to allow scripts access to running system commands via Edit --> Preferences --> Scripting, checking the box for "Allow scripts to run system commands":

   [image: preferences dialog]
6. Now everything should be ready. To access the documentation of a package:

   1. Select the name of a package in your document, for example by double-clicking on it.
   2. Hit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. (In other words, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and hit first <kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd>.)